# Is there a way to preserve tabs that were open in Froyo 2.2's stock browser?

Tags: browser, reboot, stock-browser

When my Droid X's Froyo 2.2 browser gets killed for whatever reason (reboot, memory manager killing it), it loses 100% of its open tabs and reopens with Google's home page in a single tab.

If you have 7-8 open tabs, restoring them from History (especially if some were used via Google Mobile URL that all look the same in history tab) is a uber-major pain.

**Is there a way to preserve tabs that were open in Froyo 2.2's stock browser, ala saving session state in Firefox, IR or Chrome (at least on desktop)?**

**NOTE**: "Upgrade from Froyo" is not an option, neither is "use FireFox mobile" - for some reason FF and my Droid X don't play well ([FF gets completely frozen once an hour](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22698/is-there-an-obvious-reason-firefox-would-freeze-on-my-droidx-2-2-froyo) usually requiring full battery pull). The question is specifically about Googe's Android Stock browser.

However, if the stock browser from Android 2.3 and on fixes the problem AND can be installed on Froyo 2.2, I'm quite happy with that as an answer.

P.S. Ironically, my problem is the **opposite** of the one discussed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13052/how-can-i-prevent-stock-android-browser-from-loading-last-visited-page).

Comment: If you're willing to try another 3rd party browser, Opera has always worked well in my experience. Don't really know if it will help, though.

Comment: @eldarerathis - I tried Opera around 1 year ago, and it was pretty slow for some reason and hard to use. I'm willing to consider it but not too hopeful - however, my question is more of a technical question about stock browser rather than "how can I solve the problem in a different way".

Comment: If you're insisting on limiting your answer to stock browser, there's not much you can do. Session saving is only added in recent version of Android, as it currently stands, your question is akin to "how do I do X with a tool that doesn't support X, and I don't want alternative tool"

Comment: @LieRyan - it's quite possible that there's some hidden setting in some config file that can turn it on. I mean, it's not IE6 we are talking about but a Google product :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps Chrome will work on your phone -- it works nicely on mine

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome

Comment: Chrome will not work on versions of Android before ICS.