# Is there an obvious reason FireFox would freeze on my DroidX (2.2 Froyo)?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, firefox-for-android, system-freeze

For some reason, when I run FireFox, it starts out pretty snappy, but very frequently (though not 100%) after 1-2 hours of very normal/light use (e.g. 1 tab with actively read Google Reader mobile page as well as opening [1/2 tabs at a time] 5-10 separate articles from said reader), **the browser just freezes**. Most of the time, the freeze is complete - e.g. it will sit there for 5+ mins (or forever), with no reaction to home or power keys, requiring a battery pull.

This happens at any time, from the phone being just after boot to phone haven't been rebooted for 3 days.

*System:* DroidX, with original stock Froyo 2.2 ROM, rooted. FF version is IMHO irrelevant - this is happening now with whatever the latest Google Play market version is (10? 11?) but also happened as far as 2 or 3 FF updates back as well, for at least 3-6 months. I didn't use FF for browsing before then so don't know if earlier versions behaved better.

I have virtually no add-ons installed, but can provide a list if this seems relevant (not sure how to launch in "safe" mode in Android sans addons alltogether).

*P.S.* Before someone asks, this is **definitely** not related to ATK - the symptoms persisted after turning off/freezing ATK, never mind the fact that FF is on ATK's whitelist.

Is there a usual known reason for this behavior? What are suggested approaches to troubleshoot?

P.S. The only other app which freezes the phone with any regularity is Google Maps.

Comment: Any messages/errors in logcat?

Comment: @NoBugs - I'm not sure - never checked. I will catch the next freeze (which, BTW, keep happening even on the latest 20th version) and check logcat.